# how to change the row background colour based upon some criteria in EXTJS

Tags: extjs

Dear Sir/Madam,
               I'm new to EXTJS coding.I'm learning it.I've come across a problem of changing the row background colour based upon some criteria in complete EXTJS coding.Can you help me,please ?

Comment: are you trying to change the row color in a GridPanel?

Comment: Perhaps you should tell as what these criteria are? A renderer function could be enough for that.

Comment: @michl: criteria means,if value is 1 then the whole row in the grid has to be changed to new colour. what does the renderer function do ? how it works ?

Comment: @ madhu: yes,i'm trying to change the row color in a GridPanel.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use getRowClass method in the GridView to set your custom CSS class of the row:

```
viewConfig: {
    forceFit: true,
    showPreview: true, // custom property
    enableRowBody: true, // required to create a second, full-width row to show expanded Record data
    getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rp, ds){ // rp = rowParams
        if(record.get('isRed')){
            return 'x-grid3-row-red';
        }
    }
},
```

Where you have defined your CSS class x-grid3-row-red.

Look for method getRowClass in documentation: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.GridView

Comment: can i use it for changing as many rows ....? what are the parameters inside "getRowClass:function(record,rowIndex,rp,ds)" mean ???? can you explain with an example ?

Comment: @michl: criteria means,if value is 1 then the whole row in the grid has to be changed to new colour. what does the renderer function do ? how it works ?

Comment: how is that value called into the record?

Comment: Tried this but now hovering over the rows that have this new css class don't highlight the row anymore.

Comment: Well, that was more than 10 years ago. Many versions of extjs have come and gone, and many things have changed. I suggest you open a new question with your problem!